# How to retrieve pyodbc row for given value

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a pyodbc object returned from a `cursor.fetchall(query)` command which contains 4 columns and several rows.  I would like to be able to find the index of a row (or set of rows) based on a value in one of the columns.

So say that 7 rows in column 3 contain the value 'X'.  How can I find the indices for rows in my pyodbc object where column 3 = 'X'?

My guess is something like below which of course doesn't work since index is not defined for all_products.

```
cursor.execute("select distinct product1, product2, product3, product 4 from myschema.mytable")
all_products = cursor.fetchall()
print(all_products[3].index(str('X')))
```

EDIT: added some more code to clarify my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about pyodbc but with cx_Oracle I think a fetchall returns a list of rows. So, I guess it would be something like this:

```
i = 0
for p in all_products:
    if p[2] == 'X':
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

I'm assuming that the 3rd column is in p[2].

The values of i that are printed are the indexes into all_products.

Comment: With pyodbc, `fetchall()` returns a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects and the columns in each Row object can be retrieved by their zero-based numeric index, so your approach should work just fine.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer.  This will definitely work.